# Tensorflow LSTM, Predict 5 values each time single value comes

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, time-series, lstm, forecasting

I have a parser for some web page, each 20-60 seconds I am getting an array Xt=[x0, x1, x2, x3, x4]. I am only interested in predicting next five x0 from each array, but want to use x1,..x4 as well. So, for Xt predict [Xt+1[0], Xt+2[0],..., Xt+5[0]]. Not sure how to approach this problem at all.

First I tried to break all data into sequences with `time_step=24`: X=[[X0,...,X23], [X1,...,X24], [X2,...X25], ...]; Y = [[X24[0],...,X28[0]], [X25[0],...,X29[0]],...]. Used bunch of keras.LSTM layers and the model returns same values in each column.

Now I did this (time_step=1, for Xt predict [Xt+1[0],..., Xt+5[0]]):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.read_csv('data1.csv', index_col=0)
data1 = df1.to_numpy()

trX = []
trY = []
for i in range(0, len(data1)-6):
  trX.append(data1[i])
  trY.append(data1[i+1:i+6][:, 0])

trX = np.array(trX, dtype=np.float32)
trY = np.array(trY, dtype=np.float32)
trX = trX.reshape(-1, 1, 5)

BS = 600
trX = trX[:trX.shape[0] - trX.shape[0] % BS]
trY = trY[:trY.shape[0] - trY.shape[0] % BS]

valX = trX[-BS:]
trX = trX[:-BS]

valY = trY[-BS:]
trY = trY[:-BS]

import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

model1 = tf.keras.Sequential()
model1.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(256, return_sequences=True, batch_input_shape=(600, 1, 5), stateful=True))
model1.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(128, return_sequences=True, stateful=True))
model1.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(64, return_sequences=True, stateful=True))

model1.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
model1.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation=tf.keras.activations.elu))

model1.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation=tf.keras.activations.elu))
model1.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(5, activation=tf.keras.activations.elu))

model1.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='mse',
              metrics=['acc'])

model1.fit(trX, trY, 600, 5, 1, validation_data=(valX, valY), shuffle=False)

res1 = model1(valX)
res1

Epoch 1/5
21/21 [==============================] - 6s 66ms/step - loss: 5.6772e-04 - acc: 0.2037 - val_loss: 3.7310e-04 - val_acc: 0.1917
Epoch 2/5
21/21 [==============================] - 0s 11ms/step - loss: 8.0731e-04 - acc: 0.1967 - val_loss: 3.2517e-04 - val_acc: 0.2083
Epoch 3/5
21/21 [==============================] - 0s 12ms/step - loss: 6.7266e-04 - acc: 0.2015 - val_loss: 4.2750e-04 - val_acc: 0.2083
Epoch 4/5
21/21 [==============================] - 0s 12ms/step - loss: 8.3055e-04 - acc: 0.2023 - val_loss: 7.4263e-05 - val_acc: 0.1917
Epoch 5/5
21/21 [==============================] - 0s 11ms/step - loss: 6.4451e-04 - acc: 0.1983 - val_loss: 2.0734e-04 - val_acc: 0.1917
<tf.Tensor: shape=(600, 5), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[ 0.01462946, -0.0035404 , -0.01471442,  0.01326532, -0.0222075 ],
       [ 0.01454796, -0.00362718, -0.01483804,  0.01332456, -0.02220327],
       [ 0.01449167, -0.0035699 , -0.01502049,  0.01351681, -0.02212006],
       ...,
       [ 0.01451699, -0.00386065, -0.01463401,  0.01302508, -0.02228123],
       [ 0.01449066, -0.00371438, -0.0148297 ,  0.01326665, -0.02216893],
       [ 0.01450208, -0.0035758 , -0.01488554,  0.01341164, -0.02206981]],
      dtype=float32)>
```

[data1.csv](https://disk.yandex.com/d/VnN3tFV4CtnQzg)

What approach should I use?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is based on my understanding of your problem.

You want to take all 5 attribute for x timesteps and predict only one attribute for next 5 timesteps. Supposing that for x=16 timesteps, you want to predict next 5.

Using [timeseries_dataset_from_array](https://keras.io/api/preprocessing/timeseries/) from keras.preprocessing

```
X = tf.keras.preprocessing.timeseries_dataset_from_array(
   data1, None, 16, sequence_stride=1, sampling_rate=1, batch_size=128)
Y = tf.keras.preprocessing.timeseries_dataset_from_array(
   data1.reshape((len(data1),5,1))[:,0],targets=None, sequence_length=5, sequence_stride=1, sampling_rate=1, batch_size=128,start_index=16)
```

Here, we want to do data1.reshape((len(data1),5,1) to have one feature per timesteps (5,1). Otherwise it will treat it as 5 features per one timestep (1,5)

You can verify it by seeing first example from one batch

```
for y in Y.take(1):
  print(y[0])
```

> tf.Tensor( [[5.2513130e-05]  [6.7516880e-05]  [2.0505126e-04]
> [4.9012253e-04]  [2.6181545e-03]], shape=(5, 1), dtype=float64)

```
for x in X.take(1):
  print(x[0])
```

> tf.Tensor( [[7.15178800e-04 4.77345650e-01 2.95000000e-01
> 6.57851550e-02
> 2.55877470e-02]  [4.15103770e-04 4.77803350e-01 2.61000000e-01 4.81817540e-02
> 1.53348090e-02]  [0.00000000e+00 4.77858450e-01 2.56750000e-01 5.49672660e-02
> 0.00000000e+00]  [1.17529380e-04 4.78104230e-01 2.30000000e-01 4.48042680e-02
> 1.49495100e-03]  [7.50187540e-05 4.78617040e-01 2.83500000e-01 5.70335300e-02
> 1.69152800e-03]  [9.75243800e-05 4.78693340e-01 2.48750000e-01 5.27507600e-02
> 2.45307600e-03]  [1.55038750e-04 4.78943380e-01 3.12500000e-01 7.79491600e-02
> 7.45544300e-03]  [6.50162500e-04 4.79070500e-01 3.22500000e-01 8.41833000e-02
> 3.43781560e-02]  [7.72693200e-04 4.79375660e-01 3.42250000e-01 8.51799300e-02
> 3.39922500e-02]  [2.25056260e-05 4.79435000e-01 3.20500000e-01 6.69510960e-02
> 1.01650000e-05]  [1.19584896e-01 4.79981700e-01 2.73750000e-01 5.85157000e-02
> 1.56834650e-01]  [3.91847970e-03 4.80363100e-01 2.93000000e-01 6.89749400e-02
> 5.97691870e-02]  [1.57539380e-04 4.80617400e-01 2.72000000e-01 5.25309100e-02
> 3.83557300e-03]  [2.17554390e-04 4.80706400e-01 2.51500000e-01 5.18024450e-02
> 7.34595600e-03]  [1.69292330e-03 4.81036960e-01 2.79000000e-01 5.94664920e-02
> 3.83583500e-02]  [4.00100030e-05 4.81113260e-01 3.16500000e-01 6.70532600e-02
> 8.07160000e-04]], shape=(16, 5), dtype=float64)

You will then need to zip them together to pass it to fit() method.

```
 ds = tf.data.Dataset.zip((X, Y))
```